# Title Icon image does not show up on main window when using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am learning Python Tkinter GUI, I have made a weather app using open weathermap api, However, When I want to use any icon to appear alongside the title of the APP. The image does not appear on the main screen output, Please Help. Here is the O/P and Scode for your reference.

I am using Ubuntu OS and Pycharm Community IDE.

O/P: https://postimg.cc/Lq8Xb6JF

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import time

#Function to get weather data from Open Weather Map API

def getWeather(window):
    city = textField.get()
    api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&appid=hidden_for_security"

    #retrieving json data from api
    json_data = requests.get(api).json()
    condition = json_data['weather'][0]['main']
    temp = int(json_data['main']['temp'] - 273.15)
    min_temp = int(json_data['main']['temp_min'] - 273.15)
    max_temp = int(json_data['main']['temp_max'] - 273.15)
    pressure = json_data['main']['pressure']
    humidity = json_data['main']['humidity']
    wind = json_data['wind']['speed']
    sunrise = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S', time.gmtime(json_data['sys']['sunrise'] - 19800))
    sunset = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S', time.gmtime(json_data['sys']['sunset'] - 19800))

    final_info = condition + "\n" + str(temp) + "°C"
    final_data = "\n" + "Min Temp: " + str(min_temp) + "°C" + "\n" + "Max Temp: " + str(
        max_temp) + "°C" + "\n" + "Pressure: " + str(pressure) + "\n" + "Humidity: " + str(
        humidity) + "\n" + "Wind Speed: " + str(wind) + "\n" + "Sunrise: " + sunrise + "\n" + "Sunset: " + sunset
    label1.config(text=final_info)
    label2.config(text=final_data)

#Tkinter GUI Construct

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x500")
window.title("Weather App")

#Issue is here I guess

icon = PhotoImage(file='img_1.png')
window.iconphoto(True, icon)


f = ("poppins", 15, "bold")
t = ("poppins", 35, "bold")

textField = Entry(window, justify='left', width=15, font=t)
textField.pack(pady=30)
textField.focus()
textField.bind('<Return>', getWeather)

label1 = Label(window, font=t)
label1.pack()
label2 = Label(window, font=f)
label2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Sujay `window.iconphoto(True, icon)`

Comment: ```window.iconphoto(False, icon)```?

Comment: still the icon image does not appear